# Sqlite3 database is not executing a query

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am developing an iPhone app in Xcode, I am unable to access the database I have created. Following is the code where I am creating my database

```
//create local database
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
sqlite3 *localDB;

// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

// Build the path to the database file
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"local.db"]];

NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO) {
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &localDB) == SQLITE_OK) {
        char *errMsg;
        const char *sql_stmt1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS My_choices (perfume_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, na TEXT, got_it TEXT)";

        const char *sql_stmt2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Ratings (perfume_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, rating NUMERIC)";

        const char *sql_stmt3 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Consultant_Details (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT,website TEXT,domain TEXT,domain_no NUMERIC,phone TEXT,facebook TEXT)";

        if (sqlite3_exec(localDB, sql_stmt1, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"%@",@"Failed to create table My_choices");

        }
        if (sqlite3_exec(localDB, sql_stmt2, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"%@",@"Failed to create table ratings");

        }
        if (sqlite3_exec(localDB, sql_stmt3, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"%@",@"Failed to create table Consultant_Details");

        }


        sqlite3_close(localDB);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"%@",@"Failed to open/create database");

    }
}
```

add below is the code where I am trying to access it

```
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
sqlite3 *localDB;

// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

// Build the path to the database file
NSString *dbPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"local.db"]];


NSString *q = @"select * from Ratings where perfume_id in";

q = [q stringByAppendingString:idList];

NSLog(@"%@",q);
const char *sqlStatement2 = [q UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement2;
if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &localDB) == SQLITE_OK) {
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(localDB, sqlStatement2, -1, &compiledStatement2, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSLog(@"%d",  SQLITE_ROW);
        // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement2) == SQLITE_ROW) {


            // Read the data from the result row
            int r = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement2, 1);
            int id = sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement2, 0);
            NSLog(@"%d", id);

            for (ListItem *item in self.listItemArray) {

                if(item.perfumeId == id){
                    item.rating = r;

                }
            }

        }
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"query failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(localDB));
    }
}
sqlite3_close(localDB);
```

I always get "query failed No such table exists:Ratings" in my log. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is "in" after table name in your query...?

Comment: put break point here if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO) and check this condition true or not.

Comment: ok I have put this break and the file exists...so it means tables are not created!! but I can't find why?

Answer (score 0):

Basically this error occured due to unavailabilty of Table in database or wrong query. According to your post, IT look like a error in query.

Query should be something like this:

```
NSString *q = @"select * from Ratings where perfume_id in ('12','13','14','15')";
```

Print your `"String q"` and make sure it follow as above.

Comment: Please check my edited question. I get an error "No such table exists:Ratings". My tables are not created properly I guess. Can you find any problem in a code where I am creating a database? Thanks

Comment: Please Post error log from the first method where you trying to create tables. It may be helpfull to get your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help.The database file with the same already existed at that path. So my first method where I was creating a database 
   if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)  check was false and tables were not created.

Answer (score 0):

first remove database file from document directory then use following code to create a sqlite table..

```
 if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath ])
        {
            const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
            if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_myDataBase) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                char *errMsg;
                const char *sql_stmt =
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS My_choices (perfume_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, na TEXT, got_it TEXT);" //TEST
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Ratings (perfume_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, rating NUMERIC);" //USER
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Consultant_Details (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT,website TEXT,domain TEXT,domain_no NUMERIC,phone TEXT,facebook TEXT)"; //METADATA


                if (sqlite3_exec(_myDataBase, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Failed to create tables");
                }
                sqlite3_close(_myDataBase);
                NSLog(@"DataBase created at: %@",_databasePath);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
            }
        }
```

Comment: How does that help?  You have failed to get the real issue here (and so has the OP with his "answer").  The issue is that any failure with the create process leaves a semi-created database file which cannot be used.  It should be deleted upon failure and the app should crash I reckon.

Comment: Nothing much wrong with it, but it's no different from the OPs code.